# RAXO All-mode PRO instead simple article on home page JOOMLA

Tags: joomla, module, article

HI I have problem to change content display into my homepage. I need change simple articles categories display to something like RAXO All-mode PRO. But I don't know how to insert this module into content on home page. I using Joomla 3.x

If it's impossible, maybe somebody know about component which show articles categories better than conventional.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking, are you asking how to change the name of a Category?

Comment: no I ask how to change component to display Category. Now is default but I want to change component to RAXO All-mode PRO. But this is MODULE. (I don't know how to docked it into component box)

Answer (score 0):

To insert any module of Joomla x.x you can use this tag into the content of an article: {loadposition MyModulePosition}. Then in the module you set the position to MyModulePosition and in the menu display option mark the menu item that point to the article.

However if the home page menu item point to "all featured article", you can set the article as featured and the module apears in the home page.